# How to check position of dragging view is lying over the another view or not

Tags: java, android, draggable, ontouchlistener

[image]

> I have  these round dragable buttons i am using set setTranslationX()
>   setTranslationY() inside the ontouch event for drag functionality. 
>   How i can get to know that if any button dragged to middle of the icon, is lying over the middle icon or not?

Comment: You can use collision detection between buttons on touch move.

Comment: Thanks for the help. can you provide code for that or any link refrence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you  @Dheerubhai Bansal Finally i am done with using this collision method. Working fine to find intersection between two views

```
public boolean CheckCollision(View v1, View v2) {
    Rect myViewRect = new Rect();
    v1.getHitRect(myViewRect);
    Rect otherViewRect1 = new Rect();
    v2.getHitRect(otherViewRect1);
    return Rect.intersects(myViewRect, otherViewRect1);
}
```